# jQuery datepicker month select box opens and closes immediately inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've encountered a conflict between Bootstrap's modal and jQuery UI datepicker where I can't use the month select box because something closes it immediately after being open.

Steps to reproduce:

- click button "Launch demo modal"
- click on the input box inside to activate the datepicker
- click on the select box the change the month and you'll see it closes immediately

Here is an example:

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.css"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="datepicker">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `noConflict()` while initializing jQuery

```js
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
  jq("button").click(function(){
    jq("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
  });
});
```

Refer this link [jQuery noConflict()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp). Also if the datepicker gets ducked behind the model use `zindex` css property and mark it important.